# Time between touch began and touch ended

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any method in objective-c to find the time between touch began and touch ended??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
// add this ivar to your view controller
NSTimeInterval lastTouch;

 // assign the time interval in touchesBegan:
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
 {
     lastTouch = [event timestamp];
 }  


 // calculate and print interval in touchesEnded:
 -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    NSTimeInterval touchBeginEndInterval = [event timestamp] - lastTouch;

    NSLog(@"touchBeginEndInterval %f", touchBeginEndInterval);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each UITouch has it's own time/date stamp. Compare the ones you're interested in.  Take a looke at the UIResponder class ref.

*Aside- SO needs to update their code or release an iPhone app. Typing into their javascriptoided out text fields with an iPhone is almost comical.*

Answer (score 0):

In your `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method, create an NSDate object and store it in an instance variable. (For non-debugging purposes, create one date per touch and use CFMutableDictionary to associate the date with the touch.) Then, in `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, retrieve the stored date and create a new date, and send the latter a `timeIntervalSinceDate:` message to subtract the older date from it, giving you the result in seconds.

Comment: It's my understanding cocos2d takes care of implementing these methods and abstracts them away.

Comment: @jbrennan, how? Could you elaborate on that?