# How to make sprite jump higher/smaller depending on the amount of time touching screen?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

Hi I'm having difficulties finding the correct code to apply to my sprite to allow small jump when only taped and a higher jump when finger is on screen longer. (Please find current code below)

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event:UIEvent) {



    /* Called when a touch begins */

    if (gameOver == 0){

        //Player Begin Jumping.
        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 200))
        player.runAction(SKAction .playSoundFileNamed("sounds/Jump.caf", waitForCompletion: true))

    }

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if (gameOver == 0){

        //Player End Jump.
        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, -120))
```

Comment: Well, you're not really doing anything related to determining how long the touch was... the touchesBegan and touchesEnded are simply callback events, and they don't give you any information by themselves about the timing...

Comment: Try this question as a start (it's ObjC but should be translate-able) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305597/time-between-touch-began-and-touch-ended

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828029/how-to-find-time-between-touchesbegan-and-touchend-event-in-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `update`-method. and in your touchesBegan-method you set a boolean or something like that to show the `update`-method that you are still pressing on the screen. For example:

```
//touchesBegan
touching = true

//update-method
if touching {
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 1))
}

//touchesEnded
touching = false
```

You have to change the `applyImpulse` so that it fits your needs.

Comment: I won't down-vote because I think this is still a valid answer, but, for future reference, it should be noted that methods based on chaining `IF` statements, such as the suggested `if touching`, can become really messy really quickly in the context of a game, for exploits such as *"touching"* while *"sprite"* is still in the air leading to infinite jumps unless using another `boolean` to check if *"sprite"* is already in the air; or if another action such as *"sliding"* would make jumping impossible, that would also need to be checked, and so on. A `state-machine` solution would be better.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really simple, this means when ever the player lets go of the screen he will fall and if he hold he will reach 200 else he falls

```
touches began {
    sprite.physicsbody.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0 dy: 200)
}

touches eneded {
    sprite.physicsbody.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0 dy: -57)
}
```